# IE8 DIV misaligned

Tags: html

Why would identical website files render differently ofrom one server to another? Firefox renders both sites fine, but IE8 renders one fine and one with a slight misalignment of slideshow pics. Both the index.html and css validate. Firefox does say it is rendered in quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do they load identical versions of any iframes or other documents that are inserted into the page?

Alternatively, do the servers have differing versions of any server side scripting resources?

Comment: The sites are identical. I don't know about server side scripting.
Good: http://dariaellington.com/projects/blackcatbb/index.html 
Misaligned: http://www.blackcatbb.com/black_daria/index.html

Comment: I cured the problem by creating two css files and having IE browsers use a css file with a 3px correction.